# How can I compute operations with all raster data of a specific folder in R?

Tags: r, loops, raster

I'm new in R.
I have a folder (foder1) with a series of raster data (Raster01.tif, Raster02.tif, ....., Raster69.tif).
I would multiply each raster by a number (0.0001) and save the resulting data with the same name, but in a new folder (folder2).
How can I do this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always show what you have tried --- and there are similar questions on this site that you could refer to. Workflows could be something along these lines:

Get input files

```
library(raster)
f <- list.files("folder1", pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
```

If they have the same extent and resolution

```
s <- stack(f)
s <- calc(s, function(x) x * 0.0001, filename="folder2/output.tif")
```

or perhaps

```
s <- stack(f)
s <- s * 0.0001 
writeRaster(s, filename="folder2/out.tif")
# or use bylayer=T 
writeRaster(s, filename="folder2/out.tif", bylayer=TRUE)
```

To process the files one by one

```
 fun <- function(f) {
     r <- raster(f)
     outf <- gsub("folder1", "folder2", f)         
     writeRaster(r * 0.0001, outf)
 }

 f <- list.files("folder1", pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
 x <- lapply(f, fun)
```